# Does Spring-Vault Library support Feign Client or is there any way to route the calls through feign

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, spring-vault

The idea is to make spring-vault use feign client (to take advantage of hystrix's fault tolerance capabilities).

1. Does spring-vault support feign client? or is there a work around if not supported out of the box
2. Or is there away to route spring-vault calls through feign client (sort of a proxy mode).

Following code snippet is an example for spring-vault config ; VaultTemplate bean is used for the vault operations

```
public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {

    try {
        return VaultEndpoint.from(new URI(vaultUri));
    } catch (URISyntaxException uriSyntaxException) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Some Exception", uriSyntaxException);
    }
}
@Bean
public VaultTemplate vaultTemplate() {
    return new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint(), httpRequestFactory(), sessionManager());
}

@Bean
public VaultTransitOperations vaultTransitOperations() {
    return vaultTemplate().opsForTransit(transitPath);
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
    ClientOptions clientOptions = new ClientOptions(1000, 1000);

    return ClientHttpRequestFactoryFactory.create(clientOptions, SslConfiguration.NONE);
}

@Bean
public RestOperations vaultClient() {
    return VaultClients.createRestTemplate(vaultEndpoint(), httpRequestFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no feign (openfeign) support in Spring Vault but we're supporting various [HTTP clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#vault.core.client.support) by accepting [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html).

You can get fault tolerance with Ribbon by providing a [`RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.java) using [Spring Cloud Netflix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix).